# Проблема с форматированием html

Tags: php, html, mysql, yii2, форматирование

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. 
В ide код выглядит нормально (рис.1), но при попадании в базу добавляются пробелы и потом соответственно при выводе кода в textarea код выводится не читабельно (рис.2).
Как можно решить данную проблему?
[image: Рис.1]
[image: Рис.2]

Comment: Включите в IDE отображение непечатаемых символов, и проверяйте где у вас табуляция, а где пробелы и сколько их. :)

Comment: Я даже предполагаю где они но в таком случае код будет не читабельным, думал просто что есть другие варианты)

Comment: где будет нечитабельный код? В IDE? Если вы правильно отформатируете - всё будет нормально. Главное понять что форматировать. Я не вижу ваш код в виде файла, но что-то мне подсказывает, что в одних местах у вас пробелы, а в других - символ табуляции. Банально сменить табы на пробелы - проблема решена (но это не точно). :)

Comment: может вместо textarea нужно использовать WYSIWYG?

Comment: А как у Вас из IDE код попадает в базу? Что это за странная связь?